# how to get the volume size in docker-py

Tags: python, docker, docker-volume, dockerpy

I need to find the space occupied by a volume in a container. In order to check whether it crossed the threshold or not. Suppose a container is mounted in myvolume1 and I need to get the total space used by it, free space available on it. From this, I need to check its threshold is less than 80%. I'm using docker-py for automation purposes.

Comment: @Pierre Could you help me?

Comment: @Stefan Golubović Please have a look on it